# my jquery showing this error?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get list of user data from a web service file which is called via AJAX. Here is my code :

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var param;
    var resultarr;

    $(document).ready(function () {    
        param = document.getElementById('MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC').value;
        // Load countries then initialize plugin:
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: '{keyword:' + JSON.stringify(param) + '}',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'SvcADUser.asmx/GetADUserList',
            success: function (result) {
                //alert(result.d)
                resultarr = result.d;
            }
        })

        // Initialize autocomplete with local lookup:

        $('#MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC').autocomplete({                  
            source: resultarr
        });
    });
</script>
```

`resultarr` will output an array with this values :

```
[ "Administrator", "Guest", "krbtgt", "phendy" , "Genin" ,  "Hendra" ,  "andri" ]
```

It throws this:

> TypeError: this.source is not a function [Break On This Error]
>   this.source( { term: value }, this._response() );

What do I need to fix here? I am struggling on this for 2 days, some help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a bad example of title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: "it throw me this error : `this.source( { term: value }, this._response() );`" Ummmm this is not an error.

Comment: TypeError: this.source is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

this.source( { term: value }, this._response() );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the autocomplete initialization inside the ajax success callback:

```
success: function (result) {
    //alert(result.d)
    resultarr = result.d;
    $('#MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC').autocomplete({
         source: resultarr
    });
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. The autocomplete was previously initializing with an undefined parameter for source.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. Lets examine your code:

```
$.ajax({ .... } ); // (1)

$('#MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC').autocomplete({ ... } ) // (2)
```

The autocomplete initialization (2) occurs after calling the service (1), but it is **unclear** if the AJAX request has succeeded and returned the response. There is a great chance that you are initializing the autocomplete with empty or undefined data - when the connection is slow, or it fails for some reason, the success callback might not get executed at the point of setting the autocomplete (2). The correct way to do this is to initialize the autocomplete in the AJAX callback, because then the response data is guaranteed to be present:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    data: '{keyword:' + JSON.stringify(param) + '}',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'SvcADUser.asmx/GetADUserList',
    success: function (result) {
        resultarr = result.d;

        $('#MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC').autocomplete({                  
            source: resultarr
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: thank you for you explaination, it bring me more understanding  to ajax, many thanx.